# Drawing dynamic number of grid lines on wpf canvas

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

I have a WPF ink canvas upon which i want to draw grid lines (horizontal and vertical lines representing pixelated canvas). The number of horizontal and vertical lines are going to be dynamic. I have the input i.e. number of those lines in my code behind. How shall i proceed? I hope the question is clear.